# double forEach to double for Loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an HTML table from a server-side array (google apps script; *so `tableArray` is coming from there*). I have two `forEach` functions which work. However, I'm attempting to use two `for` loops instead because I'd like to be able to add different classes to different `<td>`'s.

The output doesn't come out as expected (see #1 below). I can either get an array in one column (instead of each element of the array as a separate `<td>` or the arrays are repeated in each `<td>` (see #2 below).

What do I need to change in my `for` loops to get the expected output?

You can see the version that works [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/kytmqrvx/1/).

## 1 (works with `forEach`)

[image]

## 2 (does not work with `for`)

[image]

**Index.html**

```
function buildTable(tableArray) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  var tbodyID = tableBody.setAttribute('id', 'tbody');

  for (var i = 0; i < tableArray.length; ++i) {
    var column = tableArray[i];
    var colA = column[0];
    var colB = column[1];
    var colC = column[2];
    var colD = column[3];

    if (colA != "") {
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < column.length; ++j) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column));
        row.appendChild(cell);
      }

    }
    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of line `cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column));`

write `cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column[j]));`

You've forgotten to add index `[j]`

Answer (score 2):

```
// Loop over rows
for (var i = 0; i < tableArr.length; i++) {
  var row = tableArr[i];
 // loop over columns
   for( var j =0; j<row.length; j++){
     //create each column and append to row
   }
  // append row to table body

}
// append table body to DOM
```

For performance reasons you want to write to the DOM only once and create the table in memory first.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column));
```

to

```
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column[i]));
```

This will make it  loop through all of your column data properly instead of appending the same content of the whole array repeatedly.